# Jquery slider into wordpress or plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I have a HTML Jquery slider that is pretty unique and I want to use it within wordpress. What is the best way to achieve this? Should I turn it into, a plugin? Is their a converter I can use? Any advice, examples, or links would be extremely helpful. My php knowledge is not the best. 
Thanks in advance!

- Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way to use this slider. Put all the css and js of the slider in Head of the wordpress theme and then move to the wordpress admin panel and put the slider container in the HTML widgets(A widgets where we can put custom HTML) and load this widgets where you want to show the slide show.. you have to give the images url according the wordpress.

Hopefully this may help you...